# How can i create a different random value in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnZJb.png)

I'd like to have the four results come out in different values here. What should I do?

Comment: add `np.random.seed(value)` before `a` declaration

Comment: Adding np.random.seed() is no different from this result. There are four identical results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random numbers generation in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900124/random-numbers-generation-in-pyspark)

Comment: sorry, I don't understand that link answer...